# Internal SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I want to get PAYMENT_GATEWAY name with SQL query. I use this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT_GATEWAY(
 ID SERIAL NOT NULL,
 NAME TEXT
)
;

ALTER TABLE PAYMENT_GATEWAY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY38 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

CREATE TABLE PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT(
 ID SERIAL NOT NULL,
 PAYMENT_GATEWAYT_ID INTEGER
)
;

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP18 ON PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT (PAYMENT_GATEWAYT_ID)
;

ALTER TABLE PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT KEY39 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;
```

***select query***

```
SELECT * FROM PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT
```

As you can see I store PAYMENT_GATEWAYT_ID as number. How I can modify the SQL query to select column NAME into PAYMENT_GATEWAY and display name String as result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you asking how to join these two tables together - clarify is this is not correct.

```
SELECT
    pga.ID,
    pg.NAME
FROM
    PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT pga
INNER JOIN
    PAYMENT_GATEWAY pg
    ON (pg.ID = pga.PAYMENT_GATEWAYT_ID);
```

The above will get you the `NAME` that is associated with the `ID` in `PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT`

Another thing to note is that you should consider adding a `FOREIGN KEY` reference to `PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT` to maintain referential integrity.

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ACCOUNT(
    ID SERIAL NOT NULL,
    PAYMENT_GATEWAYT_ID INTEGER REFERENCES PAYMENT_GATEWAY(ID)
);
```

From the docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK